# Java ArrayList Construction Issues

Tags: java, arraylist, syntax-error

Despite my effort to research ArrayLists and figure out the issue by myself, I can't seem to get to the bottom of why this isn't compiling.

```
public static void main(String[] args){


    ArrayList deckList = new ArrayList(); //Cannot find symbol (1st & 2nd ArrayList)

    for( int i=0; i<=10; i++){

        deckList.add(i); // 

    }
}
```

This is a small part of the total code, but it's not working for whatever reason. It seems like a mistake of syntax, so a one-line answer is fine with me.

Thanks for any and all answers.

Edit: Thanks for answering my question (though I don't know why I got downvoted...). I don't know how it slipped past my mind to import the package since I've done it many times before.

Comment: Did you import the corresponding package (java.util)?

Comment: Please add the whole class.

Comment: Search for error messages before asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the import under the package declaration: `import java.util.ArrayList;`

Comment: Lets first check if this really is the problem, before posting it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either import the class in the beginning of the class definition.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

OR

You can use the fully qualified names

```
java.util.ArrayList deckList = new java.util.ArrayList();
```

AND

Read about Java Basics.